# Props to the React Flow custom node. Where do they come from?

Tags: react-flow

I'm reading the documentation on custom nodes in React Flow and can't understand where the `data` and `isConnectable` props come from. I don't see anything passed to this custom node in the App component. Can you clarify where these props come from?

https://reactflow.dev/docs/guides/custom-nodes/#using-multiple-handles

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { Handle, Position } from 'reactflow';

function TextUpdaterNode({ data, isConnectable }) {
  ...

  return (
   [Custom node descriptions]
  );
}

export default TextUpdaterNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I realized later, there are certain props that come out of the box, including the `isConnectable` and `data` props. Although the `data` props is initially empty, it serves as a storage for any other information that cannot be passed through the props out of the box.

https://reactflow.dev/api-reference/types/node-props